# How to find the sum of values of a column in a ListView

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sum, addition

I am Using vb 2008 with mysql express 2005
i have a viewlist box with some data like

```
========================================================
product id        product name            product rate
========================================================

12                     ANYONE                     50
12                     ANYONE                     100

========================================================
```

I want to `add(sum)` all of data given in PRODUCT RATE means column3
then sum will be shown in an text box

Comment: od you want to do it in VS2008 or directly from mySQL when retrieving the data?

Comment: if it is a ListView the rows have to be added manually, so just keep a running total as you add items.  it would be easier to use a DGV though